# How to Configure and use web Dash Board In Cruise Control.NET

Tags: version-control, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, configuration-management

I Have a single project in my ccnet.config file. I build that project using MSBUILD.exe in .config file. Now I want to see the build results on web Dashboard, But i don't know , how to see and configure dashboard to view the build status. Kindly Help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use the msbuild Ccnet task ( http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/ccnet/doc/CCNET/MsBuild%20Task.html ), you will find your answer here :
http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Using%20CruiseControl.NET%20with%20MSBuild.html

If your logger is correctly configured, the important part for viewing the build results is "Setup the Dashboard". By the way, I don't advise you to use the improved logger with the recent version of cc.net.

Hope this helps.